# How to get sum of balance React using reduce

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to get the total amount with no success in react, all I am getting is all the balance data combine together when I try to out in the console using the reduce function.

my data are as follow:

```
[
    {"account_number":"6331103626640816","account_type":"cheque","balance":"-296.65"}, 
             {"account_number":"5248117462997084","account_type":"savings","balance":"-20.00"}, 
             {"account_number":"3581474249964105","account_type":"savings","balance":"980.20"}, 
             {"account_number":"6709502417011422","account_type":"savings","balance":"905.81"}, 
             {"account_number":"5308160489139568","account_type":"cheque","balance":"-986.10"}, 
             {"account_number":"3559243852997209","account_type":"cheque","balance":"531.75"}, 
             {"account_number":"3585913435866604","account_type":"cheque","balance":"253.14"}, 
             {"account_number":"3564003756077737","account_type":"savings","balance":"896.79"}, 
             {"account_number":"3543910523783643","account_type":"cheque","balance":"-590.47"}, 
             {"account_number":"3532070362684767","account_type":"savings","balance":"58.00"}
    ]
```

and here's the code:

```
class AcmeBank extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      this.state = { userData: [], total: 0 };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/accounts");

    const allData = await url.json();
    
    this.setState({
      userData: allData,
      total: allData.reduce((a, c) => a + c.balance, 0),
    });
    
    console.log(this.state.total);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your balance is a string so you need to parse it into numbers first:

```js
const arr = [{"account_number":"6331103626640816","account_type":"cheque","balance":"-296.65"}, 
 {"account_number":"5248117462997084","account_type":"savings","balance":"-20.00"}, 
 {"account_number":"3581474249964105","account_type":"savings","balance":"980.20"}, 
 {"account_number":"6709502417011422","account_type":"savings","balance":"905.81"}, 
 {"account_number":"5308160489139568","account_type":"cheque","balance":"-986.10"}, 
 {"account_number":"3559243852997209","account_type":"cheque","balance":"531.75"}, 
 {"account_number":"3585913435866604","account_type":"cheque","balance":"253.14"}, 
 {"account_number":"3564003756077737","account_type":"savings","balance":"896.79"}, 
 {"account_number":"3543910523783643","account_type":"cheque","balance":"-590.47"}, 
 {"account_number":"3532070362684767","account_type":"savings","balance":"58.00"}]

const total = arr.reduce((a, c) => a + Number(c.balance), 0);

console.log(total);
```

With a string type `+` meaning that you are trying to join them together, so it results in a long string.

Comment: I think the first balance will be ignored in this case, it should be this way `arr.reduce((a, c) => Number(a.balance) + Number(c.balance), 0);`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ryan for the prompt answers ,I didn't think of string to number conversion.

Comment: @AdilBimzagh, No it won't. The first param in the callback of Arr.reduce is an accumulator and c is every next value from the array.

Comment: `a` will always be a number @AdilBimzagh because the initial reduce value is zero and each iteration just adds to it.